# Как узнать, что ноутбук работает от батареи или от адаптера

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, linux

Хотелось бы узнать, как из Python можно следить за переключением режима питания в Linux (читать файл как-то не круто). Чтобы срабатывала какая-то функция, если ноутбук перешёл на батарею и если перешёл на сетевой адаптер.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу посоветовать посмотреть исходники [batti](https://code.google.com/p/batti-gtk/). Он выполняет аналогичные функции и как раз написан на Python и PyGTK.